# Java 8 to Java 7 source level translator

Tags: gwt, java-8

Is anyone aware of a translator from Java 8 to Java 7 which works on source level? I want to use JDK8, however, I use GWT in my project so bytecode level translators won't work here.

P.S. I know that GWT 3.0 is in development, however, it's not released yet.

Comment: My understanding is that modern versions of IntelliJ have "quick fixes" for converting code to and from Java 8's lambda formats.

Comment: (personally, though, I use Clojure and ClojureScript for my one-language full-stack needs).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It won't work since this should be done manually.

Comment: Pardon? "This should be done manually"? What is "this"? When should it be done manually? If you mean you want to automate the translation process (though that would be the opposite of "manually"), well, IntelliJ has an API.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I need  a ready to use translator not a way to make translator. I believe that it's possible, I just don't have time to implement it.

Comment: Questions that ask for recommendations for pre-built tools are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, both Java flavours are Turing-complete, so it should be possible. But the resulting Java 7 code will be so cluttered that it will be not useful in real life. For the sake of experiment you can try to use some lambdas in plain vanilla classes, compile using Java 8 compiler with `-target 1.7` and then use JD (Java Decompiler) to see the result all the way into GWT compiled code.

However, a lot of Java 8 beauty is in new collections and streams etc. You will need to translate it all into GWT to be able to use it (this is what GWT 3.0 is busy with).

If you really want to have some FP-style code on UI, maybe trying `scala.js` is a better alternative?